# reset my application by pressing a new game button. javafx

Tags: javafx

We are making checkers and im trying to get the new game button to restart the application but all it does now is shutting it down. we have tried some things but not gotten far,

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button btnNewGame = new Button("New Game");
        Button btnTutorial = new Button("Tutorial");

        btnTutorial.setText("Tutorial");
        btnTutorial.setOnAction (new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {


            public void handle (ActionEvent event) {

                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    try {
                        File brukermanual = new File("Brukermanual.pdf");
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(brukermanual);
                    } catch (IOException exception) {

                    }
                }
            }
        });

         btnNewGame.setOnAction( __ ->
            {
              System.out.println( "Restarting app!" );
              primaryStage.close();
            } );
            primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( new BorderPane( btnNewGame ) ) );
            primaryStage.show();

        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
        toolBar.getItems().addAll( new Separator(), btnNewGame, btnTutorial);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        pane.setTop(toolBar);
        pane.setCenter(createContent());

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 640, 675);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Dam spill - OBJ2000 Eksamen 2016");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: Why not reset your game's data instead of restarting everything?

Comment: you should redo initialization, not restart all application.

Comment: `___` ActionEvent name? 

Answer (score 0):

you have the brackets at the wrong place. Instead of:

```
btnNewGame.setOnAction( __ ->
{
    System.out.println( "Restarting app!" );
    primaryStage.close();
} );
primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( new BorderPane( btnNewGame ) ) );
primaryStage.show();
```

try this:

```
btnNewGame.setOnAction( __ ->
{
    System.out.println( "Restarting app!" );
    primaryStage.close();
    primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( new BorderPane( btnNewGame ) ) );
    primaryStage.show();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

By default every JavaFX application is being closed when the last opened window is closed.

There is a method in `Platform` class for changing that.[i will add it as soon as i get back to com puter]

Although even after that it will work but what your really need to clear is your previous data.A simple way is to call the `.jar` file of your application. Wait of it to open using `Process.await();` and then exit your application.

Way 1)

1)Call `stage.close();`

2)Start your `. jar` application as a `Process`

3)When the process starts,exit the first application.

Way 2)

Clear you data of your application showing a progress bar to the user.

Way 3)

.......